# How to convert Word to HTML same as Word print format

Tags: c#-4.0, office-interop

I am converting a `.doc` file into an HTML file, and that is working perfectly fine, but one thing I need to implement is that the format of the HTML file must be same as the format of Word file in "print layout" format.

If somehow I can add footer info (i.e. Page numbers for each page) into the converted HTML file, then  my work will be done.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        oWord.Documents.Open(ref FileName, ref ReadOnly, ref MissingType,
                                       ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                                       ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                                       ref MissingType, ref IsVisible, ref MissingType,
                                       ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                                       ref MissingType);
 var oWordDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument;
        oWordDoc.SaveAs(ref HtmlDirectoryPath, ref DocumentFormat, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
            ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
            ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
            ref MissingType, ref MissingType);
```

When I see the HTML file, it is same as the "Web Layout" mode of Word, which I don't want.

I am using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library for this conversion.

**Update 1**: As you can see there are three modes to view the Word document file - Read Mode, Print Layout and Web Layout. But when I convert the file using above code, the resultant HTML file content is the same as the Web Layout Mode of the Word document. So when someone goes to read that HTML file and wants to report some error or mistake back to the person who has drafted the document that there is a date which is incorrect and you have to update it, then there is no clue that on which page exactly the error/mistake is. Because in HTML format there is no page information is displayed.

So my work is to add some page information into the converted HTML according to pagewise, so that the verifier can easily tell the drafter that I have gone through the file and there is a date correction on Page No X.

I tried to add the page numbers into the document footer, but when I convert it to HTML then there is no footer information getting converted along with it.

Comment: "When I see the HTMl file, it is same as the "Web Layout" mode of word." please show what you mean, it is not clear

Comment: Well, HTML doesn't have the concept of "pages", so the requirement is at odds with how the technologies are designed to work. Therefore, saving a Word document as HTML will not generate any page numbers or other footer content and there's no way to coerce SaveAs to do so. A solution would involve your code "walking" through the document and - somehow - putting information from the Footers into the document at the end of the page. Since this will change the page flow, you'd need to work from the end of the document forwards. Then save the document.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old question, but it could still be important for some.

HTML by default doesn't have concept of pages, but it is achivable by using Word sections, which are by default converted to HTML as easily accessible elements (from C# and HTML / CSS).

Unfortunately Word sections are not added after end of each page, but only when next page have some other settings (margins layout etc.), are added manually and probably few other cases.

You could add section breaks in Word manually or programatically. 
To do it programatically it works nice by going to last page (1st code line); then adding section break and going to previous page (1st and 2nd code line in for loop) for each page, starting with last and ending at second:

```
YourWordApp.Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast);
for (int pageNum = pageCount; pageNum >= 2 ; pageNum--)
{
   YourWordApp.Selection.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous);
   YourWordApp.Selection.GoToPrevious(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage);
}
```

You could use any other section breaks (from Word.WdBreakType) that would suit your needs.

You could get pageCount by:

```
int pageCount = YourWordDoc.Content.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument];
```

You could iterate from start (2nd page) to end, it could be a bit more messy (more extra empty lines) for some documents and less messy for others.

You might also prefer to (could be less messy for your document) add section breaks at the end of page - then you'll have to iterate from first to next-to-last page.

This method will give you something impitating Word pages in HTML, but would **work only if you have just one section - no section breaks in your document**, which is unprobable. **If you have more sections than just one (at least one section break) you'll have to deal with them somehow** - delete them (without deleting their content) or distinct from those added in previous steps and go past them in next.
Furthermore - **it will nearly always move some content to previous / next page, therefore final numbering might differ from original.**

When you got pages you could get your numbering just by insterting some div or other element holding number at the end or beggining of each section and give those elements unique class - to be adressed in styles for formating - to make them clearly identifiable as numbering.

If you want to get footers in nicer way or with more then just numbering - you might find [mvark blog post](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2007/02/how-to-add-header-or-footer-to.html) usefull.